# How can I create a dynamic web page with an Excel spreadsheet database?

Tags: html, excel, database, csv

I would like the data that I enter into my excel file to update automatically in my web page. I would also like my web page to be customizable and not just a iframe of my excel file. How can I do it? :(

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: There are several REST API samples for integrating with Office 365 located here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/gallery/?filterBy=Samples,Excel my first assumption is (and as specified on the MS developers site) to get this done you need access to OneDrive as the Excel file will serve as your "database"; you'll need to be able to use the oAuth and 365 endpoints to connect and draw the data from Excel in an object for use in your website. Check it out;

Comment: My files are located on Google sheets so I will try to use Google API thank you for the idea ! :)